# Java sockets - Closing a telnet client connection to the server socket

Tags: java, sockets, telnet, serversocket

I have created a server socket in Java, which accepts connections from a telnet client, and successfully communicates with the client, however when closing the client's socket on the server, the terminal on the client does not register the closing of the socket and does not show a "Connection to host lost" message, which is what I want.

The server socket must be able to handle multiple clients, so I cannot simply stop and restart it, otherwise all active clients will lose their connection to the server.

Maybe I am going about this wrong...? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check the (RFC)(http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc854.txt) to see whether the server should not send some command in this situation?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have found my own answer. @user503413, the RFC helped me understand telnet a bit more.  Thanks!

Comment: Please organize the response in a proper fashion and add it to the post, maybe somebody else will benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, stupid mistake! I lost the reference to the client's socket and thus when trying to close it, an exception was thrown, but was suppressed... Simply closing the socket closes the client's telnet session.